# Is it rude to ask when a position will be available again?

Tags: job-search, email

I recently applied for a job online. I followed-up with the HR coordinator who then responded by telling me I'd be contacted by one of the supervisors for the department I applied for. Later, the HR coordinator e-mailed me again saying that the position was closed without anybody being hired. I find this beneficial because the website did not notify me in anyway. My application status also did not make it clear that the job position was closed. I only would've found out if I periodically redid a search and manually checked if the position was not included in the search.

I'm inclined to write something like,

> Dear X,
>
> Thank you for informing me. Please let me know when the position opens
>   again. Happy Holidays!
>
> Sincerely, 
>   Me

I think this would be rude because the burden lies on me to check if the position is open. At the same time, I'm not sure whether or not "thanks" would be in order since the person went out of their way to e-mail me (from their personal e-mail rather than the forward-facing HR e-mail). Finally, is "Happy Holidays" too much?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I think this would be rude because the burden lies on me to check if
>   the position is open.

It's not rude, but may be ineffective.

While they may indeed keep your resume on file, and remember to refer to it if the same position opens up, it would make more sense for you to check periodically.

That way, you'll know if the same position opens up, or if another similar position opens up that you might want to consider.

> At the same time, I'm not sure whether or not "thanks" would be in
>   order since the person went out of their way to e-mail me (from their
>   personal e-mail rather than the forward-facing HR e-mail).

Certainly, not all HR departments would bother to notify you that the position is no longer available.

I think a thanks is in order here. HR (like everyone) appreciates a thanks now and then. And it always makes sense to be nice to HR.

> Finally, is "Happy Holidays" too much?

No. I think it's perfectly appropriate.

Comment: It's also useful to note, I think, that the "same position" may very well go through a nomenclature change. It's not uncommon for companies to re-evaluate the names of positions within an organizational structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably unreasonable to expect that they know when that opening might occur. And unless you were one of the top candidates, the odds of their actively reaching out to you may not be great.

But it certainly isn't rude to thank them for letting you know, to thank them for taking the time to consider you, or to say you're still interested if another position opens up. I'd actually say it was more polite to do so than not to do so.

It may not help, but as long as it's respectful and not begging, it definitely can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

It's been my experience, from 25 years in IT, that it is always incumbent upon the applicant to demonstrate tenacity in the job search process.

Do not expect HR, the hiring manager, a recruiter, or anyone else to get back to you when a position is available again.  Even if they tell you they will, the person who does is the exception and not the rule.  This isn't to imply that the hiring world is full of idiots.  Quite the contrary, they are generally capable if overburdened.

I was on an interview panel a few years ago in which a position was open for just a few days.  35 candidates applied.  In 2011, a friend of mine, who's an attorney, applied for a corporate attorney position.  The position was only open for a few days, and the company got over 900 applicants from all across the United States.  In recent years, Boeing has implemented a candidate screening process that is heavily computerized and automated because they get so many candidates applying.  Boeing actually goes around to job fairs and Worksource (unemployment office) teaching a class on how to apply for jobs at Boeing.

You need to do whatever you need to, and feel is right, to make yourself stand out from the rest.  That said, don't become a pest.  Use your judgment, and if necessary ask direct questions.  "Is it OK if I follow up with you in a month to ..."

Do follow up on Emails.  I would leave out Happy Holidays just in case someone becomes miffed that you didn't specifically cite whatever holiday they celebrate.

Courtesy and respect go a long way.  A coworker at a previous job told me the Rule of Always, Sometimes, and Never.  Always say Thank You, Sometimes say Please, Never say #$@!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you made it through the HR screening it is perfectly acceptable and really it is the logical thing to do.  Whether or not HR rep puts a note on your file... I don't know, I doubt it but who knows and the time spent on simple email might be 1 in 20 shot but is low risk high reward.

I would add though that a better email would ask the HR rep if they have any like positions and possibly could go as far as asking if you can directly email them if you see anything in the next few months.  If you don't ask you don't get (but don't be annoying).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a note thanking them to inform you that the position is closed, followed by something nice how you would have liked to work for them, and something like "feel free to contact me any time if this position or a similar is opened again".

It's not very likely that they will contact you, but it's possible. Tiny chance to get a new job at some point with very little effort. And it's good for the company if your CV had already progressed some way; if they have a new position in a years time they might save the money for an agency by hiring you.